# Issue with creating Pycharm project

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to create my first Pycharm project, but I keep getting an error. If I ignore the error and go on, creating a python file (.py) for *print("hello world")* and running it, gives no output. Just *Process finished with exit code 0*.
How do I solve this?

Project creation window:
[Project creation dialogue box image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ohe4z.jpg)

```
Pure Python >
Location: C:\Users\kolose49\PycharmProjects\myFirstProject
Project Interpreter: New Virtual environment

 * New Environment using > Virtualenv
     - Location: C:\Users\kolose49\PycharmProjects\myFirstProject\venv
     - Base interpreter: Python 3.7 C:\Python37\python3.exe
          Inherit global site-packages
          Make available to all projects
  Existing interpreter
     - Interpreter: Python 3.7 C:\Python37\python3.exe
```

Error upon clicking create on the project creation window.

```
Executed command:

    C:\Program Files\JetBrains\Pycharm 2019.1.2\helpers\packaging_tool.py list

Error occurred:

    X Non-zero exit code (103)

Command output:

   No Python at 'C:\Python37\python.exe'
```

Comment: It is. First thing I checked. Also, running the same .py file via IDLE gives the output hello world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyCharm can be a little unexpected here. Here are two areas to check.

- If you just moved from `macOS`, remember that `macOS` is case insensitive, but that Linux and Windows do care.
- Reset your Project Interpreter.  Go to the menu item `PyCharm`/`Preferences`, choose `Project: MyprojectName / Project Interpreter`; select from the list of interpeters at the top, click add, and try to add it again.
- Try restarting PyCharm with `File/Invalidate Caches and Restart`.

Hope this helps!    Have fun!

Comment: Freaky how you knew I had switched OS.
On Windows had to go to `File / Settings`, but everything else was as explained.
Solved my issue. 
Thanks a lot.